# How to permanently switch to text mode interface in fedora 23

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, runtime, fedora-23

I want to permanently switch from GUI interface to text mode interface in fedora. I tried to edit the `/etc/inittab` file to switch the runtime level. But that file was no longer used.

Then I tried to add runtime level 3 to rhgp quite found while booting i.e. by pressing e (on the grub screen). But it would temporarily switch to text mode.
So what should I do to permanently switch from GUI interface to text mode interface?

This is a new fedora 23 (workstation edition) installed on virtual box, without any changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple - just do `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` to change.

If you ever want to go back to graphical mode then you can do that with `systemctl set-default graphical.target`.

You can also switch temporarily using `systemctl isolate` followed by the name of the target you want to switch to, but `set-default` will change the target it boots to by default.